# Ubuntu Settings won't open with Gnome 3 desktop installed

Tags: gnome, settings

So I am running Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit, and have been using the Gnome 3 desktop since the day I installed 13.10. However, just recently the settings app has stopped working. When I try to open it through a search on the gnome desktop nothing happens, and when I try

```
gnome-control-center
```

I get the following result:

```
(gnome-control-center:20095): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot derive 'GnomeControlCenter' from non-fundamental parent type 'CcShell'

(gnome-control-center:20095): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(gnome-control-center:20095): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Anyone know how to fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Bug filed at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1309419 (with many duplicates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same happened to me. In the meantime a bugfix is released, you can partially sort it out by changing the control-center called from the script /usr/bin/gnome-control-center, and use the one provided with Ubuntu which doesn't crash:

```
$ cat /usr/bin/gnome-control-center
#!/bin/sh

# Support legacy applications that still refer to gnome-control-center in Unity
if [ "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" = "Unity" ] && [ -x /usr/bin/unity-control-center ]; then
  exec /usr/bin/unity-control-center $@
else
  #exec /usr/bin/gnome-control-center.real $@
  exec /usr/bin/unity-control-center $@
fi
```

--Edit:

Seems there is another workaround which allows to open the real gnome-control-center, thanks to Marius Gedminas who posted it in [bugs.launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1309419). After installing apt-show-versions:

```
sudo apt-get install $(apt-show-versions|grep 'newer than version in archive'|cut -d ':' -f 1|sed -e 's/$/\/trusty/')
```

cheers,

Sergi